# WPF - How to get code-behind Type definition for a Control from Pack URI?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a method or a mapping in WPF that keeps this data? I would like to pass URI and to get a Type in return?

I am aware of `Application.GetResourceStream(URI)`, but this returns BAML stream.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Underlying Type ( Code-Behind ), when creating a UserControl. I did it today by extracting it via Baml2006Reader, I will leave it for a few more hours to see if there is a better solution though, since my solution makes a few assumptions, and then post my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research, I did not find any method that returns the underlying type from the URI.

All that URI does is point to the resource that is embedded in a certain assembly, and I got what I need by extracting the resource manually:

```
public static Type GetTypeFromUri(Uri uri)
{
    Type type = null;
    using (var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream)
    using (var reader = new Baml2006Reader(stream))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Type != null)
            {
                type = reader.Type.UnderlyingType;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return type;
}
```

The following code works on a few assumptions:

- Build action of the XAML resource is set to Page ( It is compiled to BAML )
  [image]
- The first type that is found by Baml2006Reader is the Code-Behind type ( For example if a class does not have a Code-Behind type like ResourceDictionary, you will get ResourceDictionary as the Type ). I am not greatly familiar with how BAML is structured, but a few tests have shown that this is the case.

Tests have shown that the reader first parses the included namespaces, and then the code-behind Type, therefore a few iterations of the `reader.Read()` are called (which have reader.Type empty, but reader.Namespace filled - which we don't need), and then the part which we need.

If we continued to read the stream, it would traverse down the visual tree, and parse children types.

Since [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language#Technology) says this:

> At run-time, the framework engine extracts the .BAML file from assembly resources, parses it, and creates a corresponding WPF visual tree or workflow.

I believe it is the right way to do it.

If you believe this is not the most efficient way, or something should be done better, please give a new answer.